# How to change the starting point or anchor point of animations using pop or CoreAnimation

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation, facebook-pop

The following code starts a scale animation and it expands along XY from the center of the `UIButton`. How to make it start from the left or `frame.origin.x = 0`

```
    POPSpringAnimation *anim = [POPSpringAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPLayerBounds];
    anim.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(signupButton.frame.origin.x,
                                                         signupButton.frame.origin.y,
                                                         0,
                                                         signupButton.frame.size.height)];
    anim.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:signupButton.frame];
    [anim setValue:@"progressBar" forKey:@"animName"];
    anim.delegate = self;

//    I tried to set anchor point but without any luck
//    signupButton.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(150, signupButton.frame.origin.y);

    [signupButton.layer pop_addAnimation:anim forKey:@"signupButton"];
```

Comment: FYI: The anchor point is specified in a range from 0 to 1, meaning that (0.5, 0.5) is the center.

Comment: Could you show an example

Comment: `layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0); // upper left corner`

Comment: This should help visualize it for you: http://i.imgur.com/rtPaXVZ.png

Comment: Got it, thanks. But is this the solution for the animation start point? I looked at anchor point based on experience in Photoshop so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You are animating the bounds, but passing in the frame. You are correct in wanting to animate bounds.

So, I think this would be the correct code.

```
POPSpringAnimation *anim = [POPSpringAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPLayerBounds];
CGRect startRect = signupButton.layer.bounds;
startRect.size.width = 0.0;
anim.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:startRect];
anim.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:signupButton.layer.bounds];
[anim setValue:@"progressBar" forKey:@"animName"];
anim.delegate = self;

//anchor on the center left
CGPoint center = signupButton.layer.position;
signupButton.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5);
signupButton.layer.position = CGPointMake(center.x - signupButton.layer.bounds.size.width * 0.5, center.y);

[signupButton.layer pop_addAnimation:anim forKey:@"signupButton"];
```

Comment: that just moves the whole view horizontally to the center, guessing from the anchor point mentioned. The animation still begins at the center. @combinatorial

Comment: Firstly thank you very much for your time and answer. Its exactly as i wanted. Could you briefly explain how you achieve this with `layer.position`.

Comment: Meantime. I had made a work around by adding another animation property `kPOPLayerTranslationX`
and setting `anim.fromValue = @(-signupButton.frame.size.width/2)`
and the `anim.toValue = @(0);` but I like your solution better.

Comment: `layer.position` is the position of the anchor point in the superview's coordinate system. So I grab the position before changing the anchorPoint and then set the position with respect to the new anchorPoint.

Comment: check out this diagram... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CoreAnimationBasics/CoreAnimationBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH2-SW17

Comment: Unfortunately this way when you load a new view controller and back, this view appears out of place.

Comment: It's hard for me to solve that without knowing where this code is. I would guess you want to move this code... `CGPoint center = signupButton.layer.position;
signupButton.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5);
signupButton.layer.position = CGPointMake(center.x - signupButton.layer.bounds.size.width * 0.5, center.y);` into awakeFromXib so it is only called when the view is first loaded.